# Rejected Heroku Push

Tags: python, heroku

I'm at my wits end for why this heroku push won't work.

I'm trying to push a single python script which is a Snake Game developed with the pygame library.

using the `git push heroku master` command

I'm receiving this response

```
Enumerating objects: 8, done.
Counting objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 6.00 KiB | 6.00 MiB/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.9.5
remote:        To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing python-3.9.5
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.2.4, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.36.2
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-3.7.2 (from -r /tmp/build_85605c02/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-3.7.2 (from -r /tmp/build_85605c02/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 670f2543a9261d8b214f620cbcd3982830890dc7
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 670f2543a9261d8b214f620cbcd3982830890dc7
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to snake-game-nick.
remote:
```

my requirements.txt file contains the below data:

```
python-3.7.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python version (`python-3.7.2`) doesn't go in `requirements.txt`, it goes in `runtime.txt`([docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes)). `requirements.txt` is for dependencies from PyPI.

Comment: What would I put in requirements.txt, if anything?

Comment: If you have a dependency on any 3rd-party packages, such as `bs4` or `requests`, they would go in `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Got it, so for example I'm using the pygame, sys, random, math, and time libraries. So they would go in requirements.txt with their respective versions?

Comment: Only `pygame`, the rest are part of the standard library and are already shipped with Python.

Comment: Hey, figured I'd ask on more time. My app was successfully deployed, but now I'm receiving an H14 error. Do I need to add a Procfile in my directory? What would the filetype for a Procfile be? What would I put in there?

Comment: Wait, why are you pushing a pygame project to heroku in the first place? Are you running a web server or something?

Comment: If so, then your Procfile should be along the lines of `web: python3 main.py`, or whatever command you use to run your program. [Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)

Comment: I recently had a resume critique, and was told having one of my desktop games hosted on heroku may set me apart.